# adding prefix to tables in config/database.php with some exception

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i've decided to merge tables of two related wbsits `A,B`  to one database , so they can share some tables

i've added prefix `B_` to tables of website `B` so i can differ them with tables A  and avoid any conflict between tables with similar names

so i have tow option now :

1 - change every table name in the source code of website `B` and add `B_` prefix to it... which is going to take a very long time

2 - use prefix option in config/database.php ... which i'm going to use

but here is the problem :

there are 3 tables which are shared by both websites and they don't have any prefix

```
1 - users
2 - tractions 
3 - sessions
```

so what i want to do is make exepction in prefix for this 3 tables

basically in the config/database.php for website B i want to have

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dbprefix' => 'B_',
);
```

but some how i want to make exeption for 3 tables like :

```
$exception = array('users' , 'tractions' , 'sessions' );

if(in_array($table_name , $exception )
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
```

which is probebaly doable but i dont exactly know where and how

Answer (score 0):

The better approach will be to create views for all 3 tables with prefix B_ so that you don't need to have any exception in your code.

The insert query also will work without any problem since you will update only one table through the view.

Example:

```
 CREATE VIEW B_users as SELECT * FROM users;
```

So now in the CodeIgniter the users table is accessed through the view and will work without any issues.

Comment: i think you misunderstood !  those 3 tables are without prefix unlike rest of the tables

Comment: Yes understood it, I am suggesting to create views with prefix so that  you don't need to have any code change to prefix.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple just before you query use `$this->db->dbprefix` ,it can be over ridden

$this->db->dbprefix = ''; 
I have used like that it is working fine to me

example

```
public function table_update($data,$id)
{

$this->db->dbprefix = ''; 
$this->db->update('users', $data, array('id' => $id));

return $this->db->affected_rows();

}
```

can you please check it once

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Note:call your dbprefix in to your constructor also in that time no need call ever query before dbprefix .make sure you using model having any prefix table don't follow like this

public function __construct()
    {

```
    parent::__construct();
    $this->db->dbprefix = ''; 

}
```

Comment: thanx but the goal is to avoid changing the source code for every single query , if  i want to do that i can simply change my table name in the query  => `$this->db->update('B_users', $data, array('id' => $id));`